# SED replace in bash between round brackets

Tags: bash, replace, sed, match, brackets

I want to use sed to check if some string match to a pattern and then save that match into a variable:

```
function tst2(){
    string='cms(1.2;1.5;1.3)'
    regex='cms\(.*\)'
    echo -e $string

    if [[ $string =~ $regex ]]
    then
        myVar=$(echo -e $string | sed "s/cms\(.*\)/\1/g")
        echo $myVar
    else
        echo "too badd!!!"
    fi
}
```

Console output:

```
[user@home~]$ tst2
cms(1.2;1.5;1.3)
(1.2;1.5;1.3)
```

I would like myVar to become "1.2;1.5;1.3" (without the round brackets)

Comment: `myvar=$(sed 's/cms(\(.*\))/\1/g' <<< "$string")`

Comment: quote your variables and delimit scripts with single quotes, not double.

Answer (score 2):

This is a faster way without having to use sed. It uses the bash builtin BASH_REMATCH variable filled when the =~ operator is used:

```
function tst2(){
    string='cms(1.2;1.5;1.3)'
    regex='cms\((.*)\)'
    echo -e $string

    if [[ $string =~ $regex ]]
    then
       echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    else
       echo "too badd!!!"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`myVar=$(expr $string : $regex)`

This will do what you want (using the shell's builtin `expr`). You need to adjust your regex though, to:

`regex='cms(\(.*\))'`

That matches the brackets yet doesn't include them in the result.